# How to make a batch file automatically run itself after being updated

Tags: python, batch-file, cmd

I have edited the contents of my batch file in a python program however when I try to execute the .bat in python it doesn't follow the instructions. It opens the console and then closes but nothing happens. Instead I am looking at an alternative route- automatically running after the code has been saved or changed.

The reason I need it to run is because it updates an mp3, so if it's not running properly the mp3 doesn't change. I think one of the reasons may be down to not being able to run as administrator in python. I did create a shortcut and set it to run as admin every time but python wouldn't allow the .ink file for subprocess.Popen() and os.system()

Answer (score 0):

For running the the batch file again after it has been edited or modified, you can write a script. That script can be executed using daemon services or launchd in mac os x.

Comment: So write a batch file which tells the other one to run after it has been modified?

Comment: Yes, the first batch/script file can monitors the second batch file based upon the modified time and executes it. The first batch file itself can be part of the daemon services which can be scheduled to run periodically.

Answer (score 0):

```html
var fsw=require('fs');
fsw.watch( "./test", (EventType, filename)=>{
                if (filename){
                console.log( filename );
                }
                } );
```